# Angular UI-ROUTE no carga estilo de tabla

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap

Estoy usando Angular [UI-ROUTER](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld) pero no carga los estilos de la tabla de una de las secciones (En dicha sección estoy usando [Bootstrap Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/es/getting-started/))

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My App 2</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
        
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-table/dist/locale/bootstrap-table-es-CL.min.js"></script>
        
        <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        
        <style>.active { color: red; font-weight: bold; }</style>
    
    </head>

    <body ng-app="calculaApp">
        
        <a ui-sref="inicio" ui-sref-active="active">Inicio</a>
        <a ui-sref="donar" ui-sref-active="active">Donar</a>
        <a ui-sref="insumos" ui-sref-active="active">Insumos</a>
        
        
        <ui-view></ui-view>
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

app.js

```js
var myApp = angular.module ('calculaApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider){
    
    var inicioState = {
        name: 'inicio',
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'templates/inicio.html'
        
    }
    
    var donarState = {
        name: 'donar',
        url: '/donar',
        templateUrl: 'templates/donar.html'
        
    }
    
    var insumosState = {
        name: 'insumos',
        url: '/insumos',
        templateUrl: 'templates/insumos.html'
        
    }
    
    $stateProvider.state(inicioState);
    $stateProvider.state(donarState);
    $stateProvider.state(insumosState);
 
});
```

insumos.html

```html
<table data-toggle="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item ID</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>$1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Has intentando probar la tabla dentro del mismo `body` a ver si sale el mismo problema?

Comment: Buena observación, he colocado esa tabla dentro del `body` (es decir dentro de index.html) y si me funciona. Pero como haría para que me reconozca dentro de insumos.html?

Comment: hablas de esto, `<style>.active { color: red; font-weight: bold; }</style>`

Comment: ademas los estilos se supone yo aqui que cargan es dentro de `class="Estilo para aplicar"`, y veo que usas algo que no habia visto, no uso bootstrap en mi caso como eso de `data-toggle`

Comment: No, ese codigo que mencionas es referencial y solo lo estoy usando para ver en la sección que estoy. Me refiero al código de la tabla de `insumos.html` carga los datos pero sin estilo. Lo curioso es que cuando lo coloco dentro del body de `index.html` si funciona normal.

Comment: Disculpa, pero no veo cual se supone que son los *estilos* que quieres agregar a tu tabla, no veo ninguna clase por ningún lado sinceramente se me hace dificil, podrias poner dos capturas de pantalla dentro de tu pregunta, una cuando si sucede lo que quieres, y otra cuando no.